# TabItem without alpha value from TabLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout, alpha, alpha-transparency

I am using a TabLayout with some specific alpha value and the tab items are set to have an icon. However, I do not want this alpha value to be applied to the icons, just to the TabLayout background.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/id"
    style="@style/style"
    android:background="@color/someColor"
    android:alpha="0.2">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon1" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon2" />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

The icon is displayed with some transparency as well, but I want it to be displayed with its original color.
I have tried to add alpha attribute to each TabItem, but seems to be ignored. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a semi-transparent drawable as the background color of the TabLayout. Create a drawable with color (including alpha).

`tab_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#5000ddfa" />
</shape>
```

Use it in your TabLayout, and remove `android:alpha`:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/id"
    style="@style/style"
    android:background="drawable/tab_bg">

    ...

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Comment: The color I am using for the background is coming from some code I do not have control, it is something like android:background="@color/someColor_defined_by_a_ux_team", so if I use the hex code directly, I wont get any change in case that team change the color value.

Comment: Okay, then put this TabLayout's android:background="@color/transparent" (full transparent) and add another View same size as the TabLayout. Set alpha of that View and set background as your desired color.